# Python: Color mapping with data frames

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, imshow

I have a data frame called summed_data as follows:

```
altitude    1000    2000    3000    4000
longitude
-159          0       0       0       1
-158          1       2       2       0
```

I am trying to create a 2D grid plot, of longitude vs altitude with the third dimension (values inside the table 0,0,0,1,1,2,2,0) represented by a color map as the third dimension.

I have tried:

```
plt.imshow(summed_data.values, cmap = 'RdBu')
```

This produces:
[image]

However, I want the colormap to correlate with the longitude and altitude.

**EDIT**

When I try the answer below:

```
plt.imshow(summed_data.values, aspect = 'auto', extent = [-160,-150,0,5000],cmap = 'RdBu')
```

the figure does not correlate to the longitude and altitude specified:

[image]

There should only be color in the box with longitude = -158 or -159 and the corresponding altitudes.

How do I plot longitude vs altitude with the values in the table summed_data represented by a color map in python?